# Highly-downvoted duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicates

I've noticed that [this recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107477/how-do-you-calculate-spell-ability-and-spell-save-dc) is probably a [duplicate of this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96539/calculating-wizard-spell-casting-ability-and-spell-attack-bonus). However, as a recent recipient of the 5e gold badge, I'm hesitant to unilaterally close it as a duplicate. I have the following questions:

1. Is it really a duplicate? The first is asking for confirmation, I suppose, and the second is asking for the information itself, but they do strike me as duplicates.
2. Both questions have attracted a number of downvotes. Should this factor into how I think about the close vote, or which question is a duplicate of which?

Comment: Congrats on the hardware, by the way =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No. Usually we close the newer as a dupe of the old unless there's a dramatic disparity in quality that would make the newer one more canonical.